# Does SID change if we change the integrity level?

Tags: windows, winapi, integrity

Does SID changes if we change the integrity level?

My code is changing the integrity level and I see it in Process Explorer. But I don't know if SIDs should also be changed for a process. In this case to prove it I want to change the integrity level of the process in Process Explorer and see if the SID changes.

But how can I change the integrity level in Process Explorer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A process does not have SIDs that are used in access checks on other objects, the SIDs are part of the token of a thread/process. (Processes and threads are securable kernel objects and therefore have ACLs with SIDs but that is not really relevant here).

[The integrity level is stored as a SID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/mandatory-integrity-control) so yes, one of the SIDs will change if the integrity level changes.

> The integrity SID for a securable object is stored in its system access control list (SACL). The SACL contains a SYSTEM_MANDATORY_LABEL_ACE access control entry (ACE) that in turn contains the integrity SID. Any object without an integrity SID is treated as if it had medium integrity.
>
> The integrity SID for a security principal is stored in its access token. An access token may contain one or more integrity SIDs.

I doubt that modifying the integrity SID is actually going to change the integrity level of a process. To change the level you need to change the token.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I really change the token of the process. So when the token is changed to LOW integrity level should I also change the SID to S-1-16-4096 ?

Comment: The SID is part of the token. If you create a token with low IL then the SID will be the low IL SID.